# Flutter Device Preview equivalent in React Native App?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, preview

recently i've found this [`plugin`](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_device_preview) can preview many device of `Android` or `iOS` device in one installed apps,

> gif of the plugin is at https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_device_preview

[image]

does `react native` has something like this?

I know there's some similar `plugin` like [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/) and [Appetize](https://appetize.io/) but i need something like this,

i mean i can preview of many device in my apps, not installing my app on many devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apptize seems to be the most similar option available.

`flutter_device_preview` is certainly a more practical/simple solution. You change the parameters or device, the app is rendered instantaneously. However, it provides a first-order approximation, as said in flutter_device_preview repo:

> Think of Device Preview as a first-order approximation of how your app
>   looks and feels on a mobile device. With Device Mode you don't
>   actually run your code on a mobile device. You simulate the mobile
>   user experience from your laptop, desktop or tablet.

But with `Apptize` you will be able to run a native app, with no approximations, using a the true mobile-OS on any PC/Mac/Linux OS via web. But of course, has some limitations (currently 7 devices only), and has another purpose.

Here you can generate an iframe to start the testing:

https://appetize.io/docs#embed-your-app

[image]